# Manipulating DATEADD to display date in correct format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know this is properly an easy fix but it has been doing my head in all day! I have created a temporary table and I want to input the date for the first day of the previous month so I have used:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) as [Last Month]
```

Which is populating my table with `2014-12-01` but I want it to come out as `12/01/2014`. I have tried numerous times to make this work but I can't seem to get it to work, I tried to incorporate the `DATEADD` into the following SQL statement but couldn't get it to run!

```
replace(LEFT(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106),6) + '/' + RIGHT(year(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106)),2), ' ', '/') as [Last Month],
```

The Column I am trying to insert into is of type `DATE`

Comment: tried to use the following webpage as a reference also and couldn't get it to work: [link](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/centurydateformat/)

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0),103)`

Comment: if the column you're inserting into is of type `date or datetime` then the format of the (stored) date does not matter. Providing an appropriate format to display the date be it via a SQL convert, or a tostring method on the front end (the preferred place to format dates) is the only time you should be concerned with date format

Comment: I just realized that this is an issue because I have it as `DATE` so I would need to `CONVERT` it! DO you know any good articles on this because I am useless with these dates :(

Comment: Well, you already know the key word: `CONVERT`. Look it up in T-SQL manual, you'll find your answer there.

Comment: @Lamak: +1 but should be `101`, not `103` (as they seem to want `MM/DD/YYYY`).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0),103)
```

The conversion types are listed in the below link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: this doesn't work because I am inserting into a temp table which has `lastMonth DATE` when creating the table

Comment: @user3538102 *sigh*, a `DATE` is just that, a date, it doesn't have a format. If you want to get it in some specific format for you, then you need to convert it to a string, period

Comment: with this piece of SQL inserted it comes back as `2014-01-12` and not `12/01/2014`

Comment: have you read any of the several comments on your question stating the ***date format does not matter*** when stored in a date/datetime field?

Comment: @user3538102 I think that's what we're wondering (at least I am).  A date is a date is a date is a date... what are you trying to ***do*** where you're under the impression is has to be in a specific format when persisted or put into a temp table?

Comment: Storing in a date field will only store in format yyyy-mm-dd. If you want to show a date in format dd/mm/yyyy you have to convert it to varchar (text) - by this I mean visually show, you cannot store a date in a date field as dd/mm/yyyy. You would have to change your temp table lastMonth to varchar(10) rather than date

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` is a data type with a prescribed format, default for SQL Server is `YYYY-MM-DD`.  When you manipulate the format of your date, then shove it back into a `DATE` field, it converts the manipulated date into standard `DATE` format for storage (so long as the manipulated date is still in one of SQL's accepted formats).

You can alter the displayed format upon retrieval with `CONVERT(VARCHAR,...)`. You should not store the date as a `VARCHAR()` just to preserve a desired format type, that will ruin your ability to use the date properly, requiring `CAST()`/`CONVERT()` at every usage.